# Is there any known algorithm to negotiate a price between co-owners who want to sell an item?

Tags: asset-pricing, auctions, algorithms

I am looking for an algorithm or a mechanism that I could implement for a specific case in my [smart contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract). How can multiple co-owners of an item agree efficiently on a selling price?

I am not really into economics and all the auction types I have been looking for don't really address this case. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "*agree efficiently*"?

Comment: if possible, with as little steps as possible. A counter example would be to let everyone choose until there is an exact match (which can not be possible)

Comment: Okay; randomize a co-owner and let them set a selling price. One round algorithm, two if you include the randomization.

Comment: How about some kind of multi-stage voting, where in the first round "candidates" are several wide price intervals and in the second round the winner interval is divided in further narrower intervals that serve as candidates for the second round, and so on? If at some round it fails, the price is selected randomly from given (at current round) interval. Probably you can also add "against all" as option for voting.

Comment: @user161005 It seems like by "voting" you mean majority voting, even though social choice theory / mechanism design offers a wide array of alternatives.

Comment: @Giskard No, I don't. Each round can use, for an example, IRV, as long as there are more than two candidates

Comment: Also, why can't you just look at code of other smart contracts? I guess some of them faced the same problem and you could just use their method.

Comment: @user161005 As I am not sure about the problem denomination, I have not been able to look at others contracts tackling it yet. Thanks for your suggestions regarding voting system. It raises even more interesting question (e.g., how to chose the intervals), do you know of any other system using such methods ?

Comment: "how to choose intervals". Ask each co-owner for maximum price for the item. Out these prices choose the largest price. It will serve as endpoint of interval. Then divide said interval, for an example, in two equal parts.  Or instead intervals you could ask each co-owner for set of price points, combine all sets of prices points and use them as candidates for your favorite voting method.